# Adding an image to the Front Page

Tags: image, home

I have a JPEG image I wish to have on my main home page. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you inserted your image into your home page in CMS>Pages?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the backend. `CMS->Pages` find the page with the identifier `home`, edit it and in the `Content` tab you will find a textarea with and editor. There is an image button somehere in the editor. Click it and see what happens.